# Very long loading time for AJAX function

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I can't really find the performance Problem with the AJAX function i've wrote. The goal of that function is that i can scan a QR code and it either adds the product to the cart or opens the product depending on a checkbox.

This right here is the AJAX function i have:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("AjaxAddToCartScan", "MiniCart")',
            data: { gtin: decodedText, addToCart: addToCartCheckbox },
            success: function (data, status) {
                console.log("returned");
                $.minicart.hideLoading();
                //Add to cart
                if (data && data.Status) {
                    if (data.Status === 'Success') {
                        stopScanner();
                        $.minicart.showMiniCart(data.MinicartData, 0);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#scannerError").removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
                // Move to product
                else {
                    var productURL = $(data).filter('meta[property="og:url"]').attr("content");
                    if (productURL != null) {
                        stopScanner();
                        window.location.href = productURL;
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#scannerError").removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $("#scannerError").removeClass("hidden");
            }
        });
    }
```

It works fine if the AJAX function adds the product to the cart.
The bad performance happens when i should move to the product. I tested if filtering `$(data).filter('meta[property="og:url"]').attr("content");` of the returned html was the problem and checked the same in the controller till the point of the return and neither of those were the issue.

Controller return depending on checkbox data:

```
    if (addToCart)
    {
        return AjaxAddToCart(addToCartPostModel);
    }

    else
    {
        string URL = Url.BuildProductLink(addToCartPostModel.ProductId, addToCartPostModel.SEName);
        return Redirect(URL);
    }
```

What i noticed was that it doesn't happen with the small database (~100 Products) but happens with the big database (~2000 Products). I already checked my SQL which is located in the controller but like i already said everything till the point of the `return Redirect(URL);` works fine and fast. To check the ajax function i added the console.log("return") to the top of the ajax function and it print after 8 seconds after i scanned the QR code.
I checked the controller with debuging to check if something loads longer than expected.

Does someone know what i'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
What i found was that the cache elapses and after that it works but why does it elapse and how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixxed the issue in the end by using return content insted of return redirect.

```
if (addToCart)
{
    return AjaxAddToCart(addToCartPostModel);
}

else
{
    string URL = Url.BuildProductLink(addToCartPostModel.ProductId, addToCartPostModel.SEName);
    return Content(URL);
}
```

If you return content you can use it in AJAX by using the data response.

```
window.location.href = data;
```